# How to make placeholder work in md-autocomplete with floating label?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, autocomplete

So, I have md-autocomplete with floating label from [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete), but I want placeholder instead of floating label. Unfortunately md-autocomplete without md-floating-label can't handle ng-messages, so I have to use it. I hide label with this piece of code:

```
.hide-label label {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

but, placeholder still hidden for some reason. Is there a way to make it work altogether?

EDIT2: There's [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NnTYEIWLa409OLPPCKhe)

Comment: Thanks, I think its not possible =(

Comment: That's depressing( Maybe there's a way to handle ng-messages without md-floating-label?